Simple Lie group generated by any non-central conjugacy class?
A finite group $ G $ is simple if and only if the conjugacy class of any nonidentity element $ x \in G $ generates all of $ G $. See for example Simple Groups and Conjugacy Classes
Let $ G $ be a simple Lie group. Let $ x $ be a non central element of $ G $. Does the conjugacy class of $ x $ generate $ G $?

I'm confused by what this has to do with Lie groups? The subgroup generated by a conjugacy class is always normal.

@SteveD I see, so you're pointing out that a subgroup generated by a conjugacy class is always normal, and so we can use a result like https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1972-032-02/S0002-9939-1972-0294563-X/S0002-9939-1972-0294563-X.pdf or https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00025-010-0038-0 to conclude that, in a Lie group, a subgroup generated by a conjugacy class is also closed. And by defintion of simple Lie group a closed normal subgroup that is not central must be all of $ G $. I suppose that answers the question.
